# Camel Bindy FixedLengthRecord paddingChar and delimiter not working in DataField

Tags: java, bindy

Camel Bindy FixedLengthRecord paddingChar and delimiter not working in DataField.

Example:

```
@DataField(pos = 1, length = 5, paddingChar = '0', delimiter = "|")
```

For fixed length, when I use paddingChar separately its working and delimiter separately its working.
When i use both, paddingChar not working. only delimiter working. Is there option to use both?

this worked fine:

```
@DataField(pos = 1, length = 5, paddingChar = '0')
```

this also worked fine:

```
@DataField(pos = 1, length = 5, delimiter = "|")
```